# Use Universal SSL of cloudflare in DigitalOcean

Tags: ssl, heroku, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I recently added free SSL to my heroku app following [This blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/set-up-cloudflare-free-ssl-on-heroku) it worked great, however now Im migrating my app to Digital Ocean, I want to know if I can use this Universal SSL in Digital Ocean, What extra steps are needed, do I need an SSL certificate in my Digital Ocean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short; absolutely no extra steps. CloudFlare handles SSL certificates, cipher suites, protocols, etc all for you. You can either switch CloudFlare to flexible SSL or for Full SSL make sure you create a self-signed certificate in your Digital Ocean server.